# publish rtab point cloud from rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, rtabmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I am currently following this tutorial on my turtlebot:
http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Nodes

Therefore I started turtlebot and rviz like this:

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_mapping.launch
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros demo_turtlebot_rviz.launch
```

It all works fine but I don't know how to export the point cloud I created. My goal is to have a list of XYZ coordinates from all points. Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried to run

```
rosservice call /rtabmap/get_map 1 0 0
```

but that does nothing... and when I click the get map option in RVIZ it is first trying to call get_map and then I get the error:
[image: screenshot rviz]

rtab/get_map is in the namespace though. Here is part of my rosservice list:

```
/rtabmap/backup
/rtabmap/cancel_goal
/rtabmap/get_grid_map
/rtabmap/get_map
/rtabmap/get_proj_map
/rtabmap/list_labels
/rtabmap/octomap_binary
/rtabmap/octomap_full
/rtabmap/pause
/rtabmap/publish_map
/rtabmap/reset
/rtabmap/resume
/rtabmap/rtabmap/get_loggers
/rtabmap/rtabmap/set_logger_level
/rtabmap/set_goal
/rtabmap/set_label
/rtabmap/set_mode_localization
/rtabmap/set_mode_mapping
/rtabmap/trigger_new_map
/rtabmap/update_parameters
/rviz/get_loggers
/rviz/reload_shaders
/rviz/set_logger_level
/turtlebot/invite
/turtlebot/list_rapps
/turtlebot/platform_info
/turtlebot/start_rapp
/turtlebot/stop_rapp
/turtlebot_laptop_battery/get_loggers
/turtlebot_laptop_battery/set_logger_level
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215257/publish-rtab-point-cloud-from-rviz/) by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can subscribe to `/rtabmap/cloud_map` topic to get the point cloud.

```
$ rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=rtabmap/cloud_map
$ pcl_viewer ###.pcd
```

If the mapping is paused, you can force rtabmap to publish the map again:

```
$ rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=rtabmap/cloud_map
$ rosservice call /rtabmap/publish_map 1 1 0
$ pcl_viewer ###.pcd
```

For the `get_map` service error, I can't reproduce the problem with RVIZ (the clouds are correctly downloaded and shown). If you call it from terminal, you would see a lot of numbers printed. Note that I tested with [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) 0.10.4 (binaries on Indigo have just been released).

**EDIT**

To have the point cloud in PLY format (to open it in [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) or any other 3D programs), you can use `pcd2ply` tool from PCL:

```
$ pcl_pcd2ply ###.pcd output.ply
```

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-08-06**:
Thank you very much for your help! I am definately closer to where I want to be now. pcl_ros was a good tip. I can generate the .pcd files now but I want to have the coordinates with RGB values. So I figured, I could just convert it back with pcd_to_pointcloud. After these lines nothing's happening:

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-08-06**:
salocin@salocin-laptop:~$ rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud ~/1438846855801553.pcd
[ INFO] [1438848137.530670782]: Publishing data on topic /cloud_pcd with frame_id /base_link.
[ INFO] [1438848137.542530309]: Loaded a point cloud with 1670 points (total size is 26720) and the following channels: x y

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-08-06**:
The PCD already contains RGB values. In pcl_viewer, you have to press "6" or "5" to see the RGB point cloud. The other keys "1", "2"... show different overlays (similar to that [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nm2ggyAW4rw&t=2m19s)).

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-08-06**:
Oh ok perfect. I have one more question: when opening the file, I get X Y Z RGB values for the points. But the RGB values are float.
The representation looks like this:
1.8005456 -0.7766516 -0.0509897 4.8842062e-39
The fourth number should be RGB but how? Can I get values for the three channels?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2015-08-06**:
PCD format documentation [here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php). In your case, the RGB field is a float 4 bytes (A-R-G-B). `4.8842062e-39=0x00352f2e` -> `RGB hex code=352F2E` which is `R=53 G=47 B=46` on decimal 0->255

**Comment by [Salocin808](https://answers.ros.org/users/23159/salocin808/) on 2015-08-06**:
Ok thank you very much, it has been very helpful!